# Html-placeholder does not work with input Field

Tags: picklist, inputfield, placeholder-text

I have a picklist in Salesforce that I am displaying on visualforce page. The picklist by default shows --None-- as an option. Instead of displaying None, I want to display **Please Select** or maybe leave it blank until user picks some option from the list.I tried using Html-placeholder with Input field but seems like it does not work:

Here is my visualforce code:

```html
<apex:page showHeader="false" controller="PageController" sidebar="false"  applyBodyTag="false" docType="html-5.0">

    <apex:outputLabel value="Have you ever participated in high school extracurricular activities such as sports, bands or clubs?"/>

    <apex:inputField required="true" html-placeholder="**Please Select**" id="HS_Extracurricular_Participant__c" value="{!application.HS_Extracurricular_Participant__c}"/>
    </br></br>
```

Comment: This is due to the picklist field type, not the `apex:inputField`. The first `option` of a `select` is indeed an `option` NOT a placeholder. The `html-placeholder` attribute does work for text-type fields when using an inputField.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `html-placeholder` attribute is **not** supposed to work with field types of picklists.

`placeholder` is a HTML5 attribute and can be utilized as part of the [HTML pass-through attributes](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.214.0.pages.meta/pages/pages_html_features_pass_through_attributes.htm) on Visualforce pages. However if you look at the `placholder` [reference](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_placeholder.asp), it can be only used with specific input field types as below, and that field types of picklist when rendered on Visualforce page when used with `apex:inputField` are rendered as `select` options.

> **Note:** The `placeholder` attribute works with the following input types: **text, search, url, tel, email, and password**.

Comment: Thanks for replying. So I thought of an alternative. I added "Please select" as a picklist option and made it default but when I go back on visualforce page, it still shows none as default and it shows "Please select" as an option. How do I get rid of this None?

Comment: That classifies as a different question. If you can post that as a separate question then someone can help you for that. With this one, the original issue is answered as why you were not able to use the attribute.